# Does RavenDB internally optimise "get document by id" type of queries?

Tags: c#, ravendb

When performing a dynamic query, RavenDB will typically create a temp index.

Retrieving document by its `Id` doesn't trigger this behaviour:

```
var entity = documentSession.Query<Entity>().Single(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Does RavenDB have a built-in optimisation for this type of query?

Comment: var entity = documentSession.Load<Entity>(1); Works without making a temporary index and is very fast I've found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arnold,
No, it does *not* optimize this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong, because it will create a temp index. If your example its name should be "Temp/Entities/By__document_id"

Comment: I just tried it - i have this index in my case. Maybe you have another index that already includes the Id property and thus the query optimizer will use this index instead of creating a new temp one. However, when you have a new and empty raven instance, it will create a temp index.

Comment: In my case it doesn't create a temp index that would be visible in Raven Studio. Index name at runtime is "Dynamic/Entities"

Comment: That's strange unless you have no other indexes on Entities. I would need a running test if you still want us to find out what's going on here.

Comment: I will create a pull request on Github

Comment: Can't reproduce in a stand-alone test, so it must be something to do with my index configuration. In any case, I will switch to using `Load<>(id, etag)`, so this is no longer an issue.